# How to use multiple javascript events in one HTML doc?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, keyevent

I have a page with 2 javascript events, one triggered from the mouse, the other from the keyboard. When I load the page I can get one or the other to work, but not both. If I press a key first that function will run, but then I cannot do the mouse click or another keystroke. And vice versa. I know jQuery makes this easier, but I'd rather not have my users download that for each page, so I'm trying to do this the old fashioned way. I have read as much about javascript events as I can find but I'm stuck here with this one ...

thanks in advance, Brad.
NOTE: in Chrome and Safari I get the above results, Firefox and Opera will only work with the keystroke function

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function create(event) {
var x=event.clientX-14;
var y=event.clientY-33;
var output = document.write("<p id=\"text\" style=\"background-color: white; position:    absolute; top:" + y + "px;left:" + x + "px;\";>You're Text, your M@jesty!</p>");
}
function type(event)
{
var letter_in = event.keyCode;
var letter = String.fromCharCode(letter_in);
//var shift = event.shiftKey;
//if (shift === false) {letter = String.toLowerCase;}
document.write(letter);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onmousedown="create(event)" onkeydown="type(event)">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really look into using jQuery.

Comment: @BenM: "I know jQuery makes this easier, but I'd rather not have my users download that for each page". What the OP wants to do is easy without jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. It's late here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using `document.write()` which clears everything else on the page, including your handlers.

Calling `document.write()` after the document has been loaded implicitly calls `document.open()`, which clears the document.

So to fix this, you want to use something like `innerHTML` to only update the contents of an element within your page.

See [this example](http://jsbin.com/uluweq/1):

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body onmousedown="create(event)" onkeydown="type(event)">
    <div id="foo"></div>

    <script>
      function create(event) {
        var x=event.clientX-14;
        var y=event.clientY-33;
        var output = document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "<p id=\"text\" style=\"background-color: white; position:    absolute; top:" + y + "px;left:" + x + "px;\";>You're Text, your M@jesty!</p>";
      }
          function type(event)
          {
            var letter_in = event.keyCode;
            var letter = String.fromCharCode(letter_in);
            //var shift = event.shiftKey;
            //if (shift === false) {letter = String.toLowerCase;}
            document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = letter;
          }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great Thanks! thats exactly what I was looking for; I uncommented the lines in the type() function to create lowercase letters. It creates uppercase letters just fine with the shift key, but instead of creating a lowercase letter when shift key is not depressed it outputs "undefined" do you know about this? Thanks again.